Android 14: logcat displays only "Telecom" tag
I'm having a weird issue I cannot figure out.
I recently bought a new phone (Nubia RedMagic 9 Pro, with Android 14) and I cannot make logcat work properly with it.
By running adb logcat all I see are entries related to Telecom:
05-30 17:51:48.068  2699  3607 D Telecom : Logging: START_SESSION
05-30 17:51:48.068  2699  3607 D Telecom : Logging: END_SESSION (dur: 0 ms): TSI.iIC(a)@Bxg
05-30 17:51:48.729  2699  3608 D Telecom : Logging: START_SESSION
05-30 17:51:48.729  2699  3608 D Telecom : Logging: END_SESSION (dur: 0 ms): TSI.iIC(a)@Bxk
05-30 17:51:48.735  2699  3608 D Telecom : Logging: START_SESSION
05-30 17:51:48.735  2699  3608 D Telecom : Logging: END_SESSION (dur: 0 ms): TSI.iIC(a)@Bxo
05-30 17:52:03.849  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: START_SESSION
05-30 17:52:03.849  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: END_SESSION (dur: 0 ms): TSI.iIMC(a)@Bxs
05-30 17:52:03.849  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: START_SESSION
05-30 17:52:03.850  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: END_SESSION (dur: 0 ms): TSI.iISMC(a)@Bxw
05-30 17:52:03.857  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: START_SESSION
05-30 17:52:03.858  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: END_SESSION (dur: 0 ms): TSI.iIMC(a)@Bx0
05-30 17:52:03.858  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: START_SESSION
05-30 17:52:03.859  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: END_SESSION (dur: 0 ms): TSI.iISMC(a)@Bx4
05-30 17:52:03.951  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: START_SESSION
05-30 17:52:03.952  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: END_SESSION (dur: 0 ms): TSI.iIMC(a)@Bx8
05-30 17:52:03.953  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: START_SESSION
05-30 17:52:03.953  2699  2699 D Telecom : Logging: END_SESSION (dur: 0 ms): TSI.iISMC(a)@ByA
...

What I tried:

restarting the adb server
restarting the device
trying to only show other tags which I know should be there (e.g. adb logcat MyTag:V)

Nothing seems to work. I checked the Developer options for the device and I made sure that I have these enabled:

USB debugging (obviously)
Allow ADB debugging when in Charge only mode

I would like to know if someone might know the cause (in case it's a known issue), before reaching out to the manufacturer for support

adb logcat can only display what the device sends. May be the phone firmware has a bug? Try to disable Wifi and cellular and re-enable both. That should generate some messages on logcat. And check the other logcat buffers, may be the phone has a proprietary buffer that is enabled by default? https://developer.android.com/tools/logcat#alternativeBuffers

Thank you for the fast response! I tried disabling wifi and cellular, then re-enabling them, and something more popped out, like this:
05-30 18:30:44.850  1589 11864 D APM_AudioPolicyManager: getOutputForAttrInt returns output 13 selectedDeviceId 3

But still not as much as it should've. I tried different buffers and also adb logcat -b all and a few more appeared, but still too few things to be normal

There is a solution for ZTE Nubia / Red Magic phones with Android 14!
Method 1: run adb shell setprop log.tag I (effective until reboot)
Method 2: Device settings ==》About phone ==》Feedback ==》Click the settings button at the top right corner ==》"Log always on"
Personally, my device didn't have "Feedback" option, maybe it will appear with updates or only available in the Chinese version, but the adb method works great!
